# Facebook version 3.5. - sort news feed

Tags: facebook

I cannot find option for sorting News Feed by most recent:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4
Facebook: 3.5

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: beat me to it by a few seconds! Those look like suspiciously non-freehand circles!

Comment: @GAThrawn They're stickers from PicSayPro. ;)

Comment: @GAThrawn It's weird though. I just looked at his pic on my phone. He has a different interface from mine. There is no 3-line button on the top-left of his screen. Maybe it's a different Facebook version? Mine is 3.5 though, on a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: It seems Facebook is testing a new interface with some users. It is not specific to a particular version of the app, but appears to be a server side change. I'm not sure if there is currently a way to sort the news feed on the 'new' interface

Comment: @geff you're right, the 3-line button's at the bottom of his screen. Facebook seem to be philosophically opposed to sorting in chronological order, it's been difficult to get the web page news feed to sort in any sensible order for about the last year.

Comment: I used to have that three line button at the top-left corner. It's gone now. However, new three line button at the bottom-right corner doesn't have sorting option for news feed.

Comment: Also my FB 3.4. lost this option few weeks ago. I've got interface like in the picture and it was like that until a week ago when everything went back to the way it was. Like in your pic geffchang.

I updated FB app yesterday and now again there is no sorting news feed.